# Facebook PHP SDK with rewrite rule for dynamic url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, facebook-php-sdk

Here is the sample link that my page used to access database values

```
http://www.examlpe.com/product-line2/sales/'dynamic-value'
```

and Facebook authentication adds state and code at the end like this and cause an infinite loop of authentication

```
http://www.example.com/product-line2/sales/'dynamic-value'?state=foo&code=bar
```

This dynamic value is like lkji98. which is used by MySQL to get desired value from database. My question is how can i get back to the dynamic URL after Facebook authentication redirect

```
http://www.example.com/product-line2/sales/'dynamic-value'
```

My current .htaccess file is

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /product-line2/sales/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^([1-9a-z]*)$ index.php\?u=$1 [L]
```

index.php is used to fetch result from database. If i put redirect url as index.php then it just redirect to index.php with state and code values

```
http://www.example.com/product-line2/sales/index.php?state=foo&code=bar
```

the facebook authentication works but dynamic url is lost.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you try using `%{QUERY_STRING}` to pass 'state' and 'code' and check if it helps

Comment: yes it works i use this  ..      RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ index.php\?u=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: It would be nice if you could answer your question with the change for people who come later to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve problem by QSA.

```
 Options -Multiviews
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteBase /product-line2/sales/
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ index.php\?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```